# Why multicast IP use TTL setted as 1?

Tags: internet

I am wondering why multicast messages like the membership query and the membership report have a TimeToLive setted to 1. I mean: messages like these shouldn't be retransmitted over the net (for example to alert other router that there is a group who wants to receive multicast messages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TTL is effectively not a *time*, but a *count* of how many hops a packet may take. When a router receives a packet, it decrements the TTL and forwards it if the TTL is nonzero. So if TTL=1, this prevents the packet from being forwarded out of the current network.

Still, the TTL should not be misused as a security mechanism. Instead, the router should look at the packet's destination address to decide whether it should be forwarded, and where to. For example, a router might refuse to forward packets that have a multicast address.

See also: [Hop (networking)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop_(networking)) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Actually, before administratively scoped multicast became a thing, TTL was *the* way to do "security" (well, scoping) for multicast. Those times are long gone, though.